# Why is the domain of the exponential function the Lie algebra and not the Lie group?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

The exponential function as I know it is defined as:
$$\exp:\mathfrak{g}\to G$$
and it gives each element $X$ the value of $\exp_X(1)$ where $\exp_X$ is the unique $\mathbb{R}\to G$ homomorphism that has $d(\exp_X)_0 (0)= X$.

This definition makes sense to me (when I look for example at matrix groups or more simply at $\mathbb{R}$). <s>Despite that, in all simple examples the exponential map is a $G \to G$ map. Of course in these simple cases $\mathfrak{g} \simeq G$ so it still coincides with the definition above. Even so, I see no good reason that the generalization of the exponential map from matrix groups to all group be a $\mathfrak{g}\to G$ map.</s>

Despite that, on matrix groups $\exp$ *could* be defined as a $G \to M_n(\mathbb{F})$ map, and then you will need to restrict it to a $\exp^{-1}(G) \to G$ map, where for some reason we will have $\exp^{-1}(G)\simeq \mathfrak{g}$. Even so, I see no good reason that the generalization of the exponential map from matrix groups to all group be a $\mathfrak{g}\to G$ map.

What is the reasoning for that?

Comment: Do you know about the exponential map for $G=S^1$? Is its domain $G$? This is really the simplest example.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I looked it up now and it indeed seems like the image of $exp$ isn't $G$. The explanation I saw was from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3766220/what-is-exponential-map-in-differential-geometry). And it implicitly "claimed" that $log G = \mathfrak{g}$. What is the reasoning\intuition behind that?

Comment: You are looking at a wrong place. I suggest you at least read the Wikipedia article, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Lie_theory)

Comment: You're certainly wrong to say that even in the simple cases you have $\mathfrak g \cong G$. If $G=GL(n,\Bbb R)$, what is $\mathfrak g$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to think of this would be via ODE's, which is in line with the definition of $\exp$ you are using. Indeed, if we have an anonymous manifold $M$, a point $x\in M$, and a (sufficiently regular) vector field $X:M\to TM$ on it, one can consider the initial value problem

$$\dfrac{d\phi}{dt}(t)=X(\phi(t)), \phi(0)=x$$

where $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to M$ is the unknown function. The Existence and Uniqueness Theorem in ODE's guarantees that this IVP has a unique solution $\phi$, which is as regular as the vector field. One can then evaluate $\phi$ at a fixed time $t$ to get a point in $M$. Thus given the base point $x$ and a time parameter $t$, we have a unique map from the vector fields to the manifold.

This applies in particular to a Lie group $G=M$, which is in particular a manifold, with $x=e_G$ the identity element and $t=1$. The only discrepancy is that the Lie algebra $\operatorname{lie}(G)=\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$ is not exactly a space of vector fields on $G$, however one can, in a unique manner, produce a vector field on $G$ out of any element of $\mathfrak{g}$ by simply pushing it forward by the left multiplication operation on $G$; the resulting vector field would be sufficiently regular (it would be real analytic) (see e.g. [Left invariant vector field surjects onto the Lie algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2780140/169085), [What is the advantage of defining Lie Algebras by left-invariant vector fields of a Lie Group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4314165/169085), [Why is left-invariant vector fields needed to construct a Lie algebra from a Lie group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1194676/169085)).

Regarding the simplest example, note that formally speaking we have that, according to our definition of the exponential map of a Lie group, $\exp^{\mathbb{R}_{>0}}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{>0},X\mapsto e^X$, which is the standard exponential function, and/but $\exp^{\mathbb{R}}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, X\mapsto X$, where $\exp^G$ is the exponential map of the Lie group $G$. Although as you observed these two maps are the same up to a change of coordinates, there is some intrinsic exponential growth of velocities encoded in the first one, whereas there is no growth of velocities in the second one.